# Return objects from an array using nested map operation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The following query transform the `json` data as objects - 1st level `map` (No problem over here - I am expecting the result to be like this)

```
const customerOptions = () => {
  return customersQuery.edges.map(({ node: { id, name } }) => {
    return { key: id, text: name, value: id };
  });
};
```

Output
[image]

However, if I iterate my `json` data using nested `map` operation I am getting the result as an array of objects - (Here I am expecting to return the data in the same format as the 1st query)

```
const departmentOptions = () => {
  return customersQuery.edges.map(({ node: { departments } }) => {
    return departments.map(({ id, name }) => {
      return { key: id, text: name, value: id };
    });
  });
};
```

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to return the second level array mapping as a list of object so the final result would be a list of 40 objects.

Sample JSON

```
{
  "data": {
    "customersQuery": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "Customer name 20",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 39,
                "name": "Department name 20"
              },
              {
                "id": 40,
                "name": "Department name 20"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Customer name 19",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 37,
                "name": "Department name 19"
              },
              {
                "id": 38,
                "name": "Department name 19"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Customer name 18",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 35,
                "name": "Department name 18"
              },
              {
                "id": 36,
                "name": "Department name 18"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "Customer name 17",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 33,
                "name": "Department name 17"
              },
              {
                "id": 34,
                "name": "Department name 17"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "Customer name 16",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 31,
                "name": "Department name 16"
              },
              {
                "id": 32,
                "name": "Department name 16"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "Customer name 15",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 29,
                "name": "Department name 15"
              },
              {
                "id": 30,
                "name": "Department name 15"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Customer name 14",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 27,
                "name": "Department name 14"
              },
              {
                "id": 28,
                "name": "Department name 14"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Customer name 13",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 25,
                "name": "Department name 13"
              },
              {
                "id": 26,
                "name": "Department name 13"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Customer name 12",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 23,
                "name": "Department name 12"
              },
              {
                "id": 24,
                "name": "Department name 12"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Customer name 11",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 21,
                "name": "Department name 11"
              },
              {
                "id": 22,
                "name": "Department name 11"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Customer name 10",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Department name 10"
              },
              {
                "id": 14,
                "name": "Department name 10"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Customer name 9",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Department name 9"
              },
              {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Department name 9"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Customer name 8",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 19,
                "name": "Department name 8"
              },
              {
                "id": 20,
                "name": "Department name 8"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Customer name 7",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 15,
                "name": "Department name 7"
              },
              {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Department name 7"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Customer name 6",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "Department name 6"
              },
              {
                "id": 18,
                "name": "Department name 6"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Customer name 5",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Department name 5"
              },
              {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Department name 5"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Customer name 4",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "Department name 4"
              },
              {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Department name 4"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Customer name 3",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Department name 3"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Department name 3"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Customer name 2",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Department name 2"
              },
              {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Department name 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Customer name 1",
            "departments": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Department name 1"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Department name 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For reference this is how my GraphQL query looks like[image]

Comment: Post your code, not screenshots. It's very hard for anybody to work with the screenshot. Help people to help you.

Comment: `map` will only return an array of the same number of items.

Comment: `map` returns an array, so if you `map` inside your `map` you are going to get an array of arrays. I think what you are looking to do here is to *flatten* that array or arrays into a single array. Right? If that's the case, you probably want to look at `reduce` rather than `map` (even though you'll be using it to increase rather than reduce)

Comment: @MattBurland - Yes that's what I am after - To flatten that array into a single array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the outer function call a `reduce()` instead of a `map()` and `concat()` or `push.apply()` the inner `map()` in the reducer function:

#### Using `concat()`:

```js
let customersQuery = {"edges":[{"node":{"id":20,"name":"Customer name 20","departments":[{"id":39,"name":"Department name 20"},{"id":40,"name":"Department name 20"}]}},{"node":{"id":19,"name":"Customer name 19","departments":[{"id":37,"name":"Department name 19"},{"id":38,"name":"Department name 19"}]}},{"node":{"id":18,"name":"Customer name 18","departments":[{"id":35,"name":"Department name 18"},{"id":36,"name":"Department name 18"}]}},{"node":{"id":17,"name":"Customer name 17","departments":[{"id":33,"name":"Department name 17"},{"id":34,"name":"Department name 17"}]}},{"node":{"id":16,"name":"Customer name 16","departments":[{"id":31,"name":"Department name 16"},{"id":32,"name":"Department name 16"}]}},{"node":{"id":15,"name":"Customer name 15","departments":[{"id":29,"name":"Department name 15"},{"id":30,"name":"Department name 15"}]}},{"node":{"id":14,"name":"Customer name 14","departments":[{"id":27,"name":"Department name 14"},{"id":28,"name":"Department name 14"}]}},{"node":{"id":13,"name":"Customer name 13","departments":[{"id":25,"name":"Department name 13"},{"id":26,"name":"Department name 13"}]}},{"node":{"id":12,"name":"Customer name 12","departments":[{"id":23,"name":"Department name 12"},{"id":24,"name":"Department name 12"}]}},{"node":{"id":11,"name":"Customer name 11","departments":[{"id":21,"name":"Department name 11"},{"id":22,"name":"Department name 11"}]}},{"node":{"id":10,"name":"Customer name 10","departments":[{"id":13,"name":"Department name 10"},{"id":14,"name":"Department name 10"}]}},{"node":{"id":9,"name":"Customer name 9","departments":[{"id":11,"name":"Department name 9"},{"id":12,"name":"Department name 9"}]}},{"node":{"id":8,"name":"Customer name 8","departments":[{"id":19,"name":"Department name 8"},{"id":20,"name":"Department name 8"}]}},{"node":{"id":7,"name":"Customer name 7","departments":[{"id":15,"name":"Department name 7"},{"id":16,"name":"Department name 7"}]}},{"node":{"id":6,"name":"Customer name 6","departments":[{"id":17,"name":"Department name 6"},{"id":18,"name":"Department name 6"}]}},{"node":{"id":5,"name":"Customer name 5","departments":[{"id":9,"name":"Department name 5"},{"id":10,"name":"Department name 5"}]}},{"node":{"id":4,"name":"Customer name 4","departments":[{"id":7,"name":"Department name 4"},{"id":8,"name":"Department name 4"}]}},{"node":{"id":3,"name":"Customer name 3","departments":[{"id":5,"name":"Department name 3"},{"id":6,"name":"Department name 3"}]}},{"node":{"id":2,"name":"Customer name 2","departments":[{"id":3,"name":"Department name 2"},{"id":4,"name":"Department name 2"}]}},{"node":{"id":1,"name":"Customer name 1","departments":[{"id":1,"name":"Department name 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Department name 1"}]}}]};

const departmentOptions = () => {
  return customersQuery.edges.reduce((result, { node: { departments } }) => {
    return result.concat(departments.map(({ id, name }) => {
      return { key: id, text: name, value: id };
    }));
  }, []);
};

console.log(departmentOptions());
```

#### Using `push.apply()`:

```js
let customersQuery = {"edges":[{"node":{"id":20,"name":"Customer name 20","departments":[{"id":39,"name":"Department name 20"},{"id":40,"name":"Department name 20"}]}},{"node":{"id":19,"name":"Customer name 19","departments":[{"id":37,"name":"Department name 19"},{"id":38,"name":"Department name 19"}]}},{"node":{"id":18,"name":"Customer name 18","departments":[{"id":35,"name":"Department name 18"},{"id":36,"name":"Department name 18"}]}},{"node":{"id":17,"name":"Customer name 17","departments":[{"id":33,"name":"Department name 17"},{"id":34,"name":"Department name 17"}]}},{"node":{"id":16,"name":"Customer name 16","departments":[{"id":31,"name":"Department name 16"},{"id":32,"name":"Department name 16"}]}},{"node":{"id":15,"name":"Customer name 15","departments":[{"id":29,"name":"Department name 15"},{"id":30,"name":"Department name 15"}]}},{"node":{"id":14,"name":"Customer name 14","departments":[{"id":27,"name":"Department name 14"},{"id":28,"name":"Department name 14"}]}},{"node":{"id":13,"name":"Customer name 13","departments":[{"id":25,"name":"Department name 13"},{"id":26,"name":"Department name 13"}]}},{"node":{"id":12,"name":"Customer name 12","departments":[{"id":23,"name":"Department name 12"},{"id":24,"name":"Department name 12"}]}},{"node":{"id":11,"name":"Customer name 11","departments":[{"id":21,"name":"Department name 11"},{"id":22,"name":"Department name 11"}]}},{"node":{"id":10,"name":"Customer name 10","departments":[{"id":13,"name":"Department name 10"},{"id":14,"name":"Department name 10"}]}},{"node":{"id":9,"name":"Customer name 9","departments":[{"id":11,"name":"Department name 9"},{"id":12,"name":"Department name 9"}]}},{"node":{"id":8,"name":"Customer name 8","departments":[{"id":19,"name":"Department name 8"},{"id":20,"name":"Department name 8"}]}},{"node":{"id":7,"name":"Customer name 7","departments":[{"id":15,"name":"Department name 7"},{"id":16,"name":"Department name 7"}]}},{"node":{"id":6,"name":"Customer name 6","departments":[{"id":17,"name":"Department name 6"},{"id":18,"name":"Department name 6"}]}},{"node":{"id":5,"name":"Customer name 5","departments":[{"id":9,"name":"Department name 5"},{"id":10,"name":"Department name 5"}]}},{"node":{"id":4,"name":"Customer name 4","departments":[{"id":7,"name":"Department name 4"},{"id":8,"name":"Department name 4"}]}},{"node":{"id":3,"name":"Customer name 3","departments":[{"id":5,"name":"Department name 3"},{"id":6,"name":"Department name 3"}]}},{"node":{"id":2,"name":"Customer name 2","departments":[{"id":3,"name":"Department name 2"},{"id":4,"name":"Department name 2"}]}},{"node":{"id":1,"name":"Customer name 1","departments":[{"id":1,"name":"Department name 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Department name 1"}]}}]};

const departmentOptions = () => {
  return customersQuery.edges.reduce((result, { node: { departments } }) => {
    result.push.apply(result, departments.map(({ id, name }) => {
      return { key: id, text: name, value: id };
    }));
    
    return result;
  }, []);
};

console.log(departmentOptions());
```

`concat()` is better if your inner arrays are very large, as it uses heap memory at the downside of copying the data from the `result` array into a new one each time.

`push.apply()` is better if your inner arrays are relatively small, as it uses stack memory, and appends the data to the end of the existing `result` array, and does not perform an explicit copy each time.

Comment: With `push.apply()` I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

Comment: Probably, I should use `reduce` for my first function too when I am using `map` for the first level arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` and `forEach` to push to an array each department data.

```js
const customersQuery = {"edges":[{"node":{"id":20,"name":"Customer name 20","departments":[{"id":39,"name":"Department name 20"},{"id":40,"name":"Department name 20"}]}},{"node":{"id":19,"name":"Customer name 19","departments":[{"id":37,"name":"Department name 19"},{"id":38,"name":"Department name 19"}]}},{"node":{"id":18,"name":"Customer name 18","departments":[{"id":35,"name":"Department name 18"},{"id":36,"name":"Department name 18"}]}},{"node":{"id":17,"name":"Customer name 17","departments":[{"id":33,"name":"Department name 17"},{"id":34,"name":"Department name 17"}]}},{"node":{"id":16,"name":"Customer name 16","departments":[{"id":31,"name":"Department name 16"},{"id":32,"name":"Department name 16"}]}},{"node":{"id":15,"name":"Customer name 15","departments":[{"id":29,"name":"Department name 15"},{"id":30,"name":"Department name 15"}]}},{"node":{"id":14,"name":"Customer name 14","departments":[{"id":27,"name":"Department name 14"},{"id":28,"name":"Department name 14"}]}},{"node":{"id":13,"name":"Customer name 13","departments":[{"id":25,"name":"Department name 13"},{"id":26,"name":"Department name 13"}]}},{"node":{"id":12,"name":"Customer name 12","departments":[{"id":23,"name":"Department name 12"},{"id":24,"name":"Department name 12"}]}},{"node":{"id":11,"name":"Customer name 11","departments":[{"id":21,"name":"Department name 11"},{"id":22,"name":"Department name 11"}]}},{"node":{"id":10,"name":"Customer name 10","departments":[{"id":13,"name":"Department name 10"},{"id":14,"name":"Department name 10"}]}},{"node":{"id":9,"name":"Customer name 9","departments":[{"id":11,"name":"Department name 9"},{"id":12,"name":"Department name 9"}]}},{"node":{"id":8,"name":"Customer name 8","departments":[{"id":19,"name":"Department name 8"},{"id":20,"name":"Department name 8"}]}},{"node":{"id":7,"name":"Customer name 7","departments":[{"id":15,"name":"Department name 7"},{"id":16,"name":"Department name 7"}]}},{"node":{"id":6,"name":"Customer name 6","departments":[{"id":17,"name":"Department name 6"},{"id":18,"name":"Department name 6"}]}},{"node":{"id":5,"name":"Customer name 5","departments":[{"id":9,"name":"Department name 5"},{"id":10,"name":"Department name 5"}]}},{"node":{"id":4,"name":"Customer name 4","departments":[{"id":7,"name":"Department name 4"},{"id":8,"name":"Department name 4"}]}},{"node":{"id":3,"name":"Customer name 3","departments":[{"id":5,"name":"Department name 3"},{"id":6,"name":"Department name 3"}]}},{"node":{"id":2,"name":"Customer name 2","departments":[{"id":3,"name":"Department name 2"},{"id":4,"name":"Department name 2"}]}},{"node":{"id":1,"name":"Customer name 1","departments":[{"id":1,"name":"Department name 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Department name 1"}]}}]};

const departmentOptions = () => {
  return customersQuery.edges.reduce((acc, { node: { departments } }) => {
    departments.forEach(({ id, name }) => {
      acc.push({ key: id, text: name, value: id });
    });
    
    return acc;
  }, []);
};

console.log(departmentOptions());
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` doesn't change array length because it works on item level. You need to flatten resulting array. For example with `concat`

```
const departmentOptions = () => {
  return [].concat.apply([], customersQuery.edges.map(({ node: { departments } }) => {
    return departments.map(({ id, name }) => {
      return { key: id, text: name, value: id };
    });
  }));
};
```

Or using spread

```
const departmentOptions = () => {
  return [].concat(...customersQuery.edges.map(({ node: { departments } }) => {
    return departments.map(({ id, name }) => {
      return { key: id, text: name, value: id };
    });
  }));
};
```

Comment: While your answer is perfectly valid, might I suggest in the first block using `Array.prototype.concat` instead of `[].concat`? I know it's not a big deal but it does create an unused array that immediately gets garbage collected, and while it's easier to type, it doesn't really make as much sense.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts IMHO `[].concat` is less cryptic. I doubt it wiil make any performance difference assuming this code creates intermediate array for each item.

Comment: I wasn't trying to suggest it makes a performance difference, I was mainly making a stylistic recommendation, it's fine if you don't agree.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No offense do you really like `Array.prototype.concat` more than `[].concat`? :)

Comment: Yes, I do, but I normally save it to a scoped variable `const concat = Array.prototype.concat.bind([])` for re-use so it's not as verbose if I do it in more than one place in the file, and I don't have to call `.apply()` with a `this` argument (or something like that, I forget exactly how I `bind()` it)

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat. I hope I used this phrase correctly:)